# iOS CGAffineTransformScale keep left anchor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cgaffinetransformscale

I am using `CGAffineTransformScale` to scale down my `UITableView`, it is scaling it down correctly but i can't seem to set the anchor point correctly.

```
self.myTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.8, 0.8);
```

If I don't set the anchor point it scales it down from the center but as my requirement I need to keep the **left top corner point fixed**. For this I've used this

```
self.myTableView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
self.myTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.8, 0.8);
```

But this doesn't set the anchor correctly.. One more thing I haven't used `AutoLayout`

Please can anyone help me out on this…? thanks in advance..

Comment: hello is there anyone who can help…?

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26365431/3195886

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
[self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0.5) forView:recognizer.view]; // for left anchor point
```

and here setAnchorPoint

```
-(void)setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view
{
CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x,
                               view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);
CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x,
                               view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y);

newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, view.transform);
oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, view.transform);

CGPoint position = view.layer.position;

position.x -= oldPoint.x;
position.x += newPoint.x;

position.y -= oldPoint.y;
position.y += newPoint.y;

view.layer.position = position;
view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what u did here? it would be great to understand it.