# iOS 8 UITableView rotation bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

So after compiling an app on XCode 6, I noticed a strange bug that happens only when running on iOS 8:
The `UITableView` takes the wrong *inner* dimensions after updating its frame.

Now I'll try to explain the exact situation:
We have a `UITableView` rotated on its side, which basically makes a horizontal `UITableView`. It happens through `tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);`.
Now after setting the transform, and then settings its frame - everything is fine.
But of course the system in most cases sends the parent another frame change because it needs to set the parent to the real sizes and not the XIB sizes or any initialization size. In that moment - when I relayout the subviews, including the table view - everything goes wrong.
Actually the frame of the table view is simply set to the `bounds` of the containing view, but then the inner scrollview (In iOS 8 the `UITableView` has another `UIScrollView` inside it, called `UITableViewWrapperView`. As `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` by itself, I can't figure out why they needed another one...) takes a "height" which equals the parent width. And "height" is actually the `width` property, only rotated.

Now we can easily estimate the they have a bug with relating the width of the inner `UIScrollView` to the actual width of the parent `UITableView`, which could possibly be by reading the `.frame.size.width` instead of the `.bounds.size.width`. 
But the strange thing is that when investigating the frame of the subviews of the `UITableView`- it seems that they are all good! So it must be a *rendering* problem somewhere.

So we are left with a horizontal table which has a blank gap on top, because the "height" of the cells is 320 instead of 568, while the "width" of the cells is fine, set to 320.

I'll be very happy to hear from other people experiencing this problem (Or from Apple), but I have finally found a solution and posting it here with the question, for future reference for me and for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the change that made it behave, was instead of doing this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    tableView.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

I have reset the transform, set the frame to the bounds which the UITableView would expect locally after the transform, and then set the transform and set the correct frame. This is a bit confusing, but here it goes:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.f)
    {
        // iOS 8 layout bug! Table's "height" taken from "width" after changing frame. But then if we cancel transform, set width/height to the final width/height, and rotate it and set to the virtual width/height - it works!

        CGRect rotatedFrame = self.bounds,
        unrotatedFrame = rotatedFrame;
        unrotatedFrame.size.width = rotatedFrame.size.height;
        unrotatedFrame.size.height = rotatedFrame.size.width;

        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        tableView.frame = unrotatedFrame;
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);
        tableView.frame = rotatedFrame;
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.frame = self.bounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly this works on the simulator for me, but not on an actual iPad

Comment: Well it works for me - then maybe you are doing something differently when working on an iPad? Maybe a different orientation? Or a different iOS version?

Comment: Turns out there's another detail. You must not set the tableView's frame before running the code you pasted in your answer. I was setting tableView.frame = self.bounds, then calling your workaround code (CGRect rotatedFrame = tableView.frame; etc). This causes the sim to work fine, but a real device to exhibit the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a new problem with iOS8. When you want to rotate an object it no longer appears to rotate around the upper left corner of the object's frame.

Apple docs for iOS8 state that "an object is rotated about it's center point". So when a vertical UITableView is rotated 90 degrees, it may disappear from view because the center point may be off the visible area. In order to make the table appear as if it was rotated about the upper left corner of the table, you must now also translate the frame by an amount equal to the difference between the frame width and frame height.

It's important to note you need to concatenate the transforms in order to get the desired result, like the following:

First create a 90 degree rotation transform:

```
    CGAffineTransform xform_rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
```

Then create a translation amount variable equal to the difference between table width and height:

```
float translateAmount = (camThumbsTableView.frame.size.height/2)-(camThumbsTableView.frame.size.width/2);
```

Then concatenate the original rotation transform with the translation:

```
    CGAffineTransform xform_total = CGAffineTransformTranslate(xform_rotate, translateAmount, translateAmount);
```

When done, you can now transform your tableView as follows:

```
    self.camThumbsTableView.transform = xform_total;
```

This will have the effect of both rotating and translating your tableView such that it now appears to have been rotated around the upper left corner of the tableView instead of about the center point.

Comment: That's definitely *not* the problem. As I do set the frame *after* the rotation, and do not care about the `anchorPoint`. There's a simple rotation transform of 90 degress, nothing to concatenate to.
Thanks for the try though :-) But this answer belongs in other question...

Comment: I do feel there is a bug somewhere, but my code DOES work for iPhone. For iPad, I think I see your point. The table appears to rotate, but the frame does not. So on iPad you need to set the frame in your storyboard exactly how you want it AFTER the rotation, and it will not move even if you rotate the table. But for iPhone is works differently. For iPhone, when you rotate the table the frame moves with it! So on the iPhone storyboard, you need to set the frame how you want it BEFORE the rotation, and then it rotates according to the above. Go figure.

Comment: Well if that was my problem, I would not even complain. Because that is something that you can still control... But what happens to me is that the rendering *inside* the tableview is messed up! So I found a hack to cause it to recalculate its inner bounds, but it's not pretty.

Comment: Yeah I get it. Problem is after we hack out a solution, then Apple will fix the bug and we'll have to back out all the changes :<0

Comment: That answer actually helped me. I was having the exact problem and your rotation calculation helped. In addition, before ios 8 we need to set the frame just like it is, assuming that it's a horizontal table view. But after ios 8 now we need to set the frame like it's vertical. The rotation changes the frame too.